# How to resume app by notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have an app with some intents, and notification reciever. When notification is recieved I want to launch or resume app. But I don't want to resume only one defined intent, but app with last active intent. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum and a static variable to track last active activity, and when you receive you notification map that variable to corresponding activity and start it.

Comment: There is one more thing: we cannot bind the servicce with activity, so we can put some data only when we start the service.